# Find the rational roots of $x^{3}-{2x^{2}\over 3}+3x-2$

Tags: polynomials, roots

I need to find the rational roots of $$x^{3}-{2x^{2}\over 3}+3x-2$$
I thought about using descartes´ rational root theorem but I need to have integers as coefficients of my polynomial: can I work with this polynomial$$3x^{3}-2x^{2}+9x-6$$ ? and use the theorem to find the roots? I will appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The solutions to $f(x)=0$ are the same as $kf(x)=0$ if $k\ne0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the two polynomials:
$$
p(x) = x^3 - \frac{2x^2}{3} + 3x - 2 \\
q(x) = 3x^3 - 2x^2 + 9x - 6
$$
are entirely different functions, however in the perspective of roots, they clearly have the same roots. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $q(x)$. Then we have that
$$
0 = q(\alpha) = 3\alpha^3 - 2\alpha^2 + 9\alpha - 6\alpha \implies 0 = \frac{0}{3} = \alpha^3 - \frac{2\alpha^2}{3} + 3\alpha - 2 \implies p(\alpha)= 0
$$
which means then that $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$. Likewise one can show if $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$ then it's a root of $q(x)$. If you're curious about this sort of process you can look into the [content of a polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Content.html) and [primitive polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePart.html) and [Guass' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29).

Now for your problem we can factor $q(x)$ using the rational roots theorem like so:

We are looking for elements $\alpha = \frac{p}{q}$ where $p \mid -6$ and $q \mid 3$. Clearly $q = \pm3 \lor q = \pm1$ and $p = \pm6 \lor p = \pm3 \lor p \mid \pm2 \lor p \mid \pm 1$. I'm sure from here you see how to check the cases and find the roots. If you need help let me know, but I found while learning these things it was good to try and do them by myself entirely.

Comment: thanks a lot DanZimm!!! really appreciate your help :D

Comment: @user140027 No problem, glad to help! If one of these good answers has answered your question then mark it as so! :D

Answer (score 1):

Factorise

$3x^3-2x^2+9x-6=0 \implies (3x-2)x^2+3(3x-2)=0 \implies  (3 x-2) (x^2+3) = 0$

For the original

$x^3-\frac 2 3x^2+3x-2=0 \implies (x-\frac 2 3)x^2+3(x-\frac 2 3)=0 \implies  (x-\frac 2 3) (x^2+3) = 0$

Same roots. $\checkmark$

Comment: By the way, I would say that an **equation** has "roots", a **polynomial** has "zeroes".

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3-\frac{2x^2}{3}+3x-2=0$$
$$3x^3-2x^2+9x-6=0$$
Possible roots from rational root theorem: $\pm\{1, \ 2, \ 3, \ 6, \ \frac 13, \ \frac 23\}$

After trying the possible roots, I found out that $x=\frac 23$ is a root (it makes the equation equal to $0$). Using long division, you can find out that the other factor is $x^2+3$, which does not have any real roots.
$$3x^3-2x^3+9x-6=\left(x-\frac 23\right)\left(x^2+3\right)$$
The only rational root is:
$$\color{green}{x=\frac 23}$$
The reason why you can work with $3x^3-2x^2+9x-6$ is because it has the same roots as the original. You actually multiply both sides by $3$ to get $3x^3-2x^2+9x-6$. $0\times 3=0$, so $3x^3-2x^2+9x-6$ still equals $0$.

Comment: thank you JChau!! :D I appreciate your help